# How can my app retrieve live tile of another app?

Tags: uwp, live-tile, desktop-bridge

I am making a custom shell for Windows 10, and was curious if it is possible for my shell to display live tiles of other installed apps similar to how start menu does that?

Of course, the shell is running with unrestricted permissions (its a desktop bridge app).

Comment: Have you found something, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any public APIs for doing that.